# Typesetting inline row vector

Tags: amsmath, matrices, inline, vector

I have (another) question on typesetting inline row vectors. 
I'm using amsmath and mathtools. I'm aware of the smallmatrix environment. Unfortunately, the elements of the vector get scaled. This seems completely unnecessary to me. Also the bmatrix environment is not a solution for me, since the delimiters are larger than "normal" text brackets.

I'd like to have something more like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text $[\,x^* \quad  y^*\,]^*$
instead of
$
\begin{bmatrix}
x^* & y^* 
\end{bmatrix}^*
or
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
x^* & y^* 
\end{bsmallmatrix}^*
$    

\end{document}
```

Is there a package that can handle this special case for an arbitrary number of elements in the row vector?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend a general solution so that you can change the behaviour later, apart from using a more clean input code. Here's one with expl3.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse,mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \vect { s o m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
   { \vectaux*{#3} }
   { \IfValueTF {#2} { \vectaux[#2]{#3} } { \vectaux{#3} } }
  ^*
 }

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX \vectaux [1] {\lbrack} {\rbrack}
 { \, \dbacc_vect:n { #1 } \, }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dbacc_vect:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \enspace }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Text
$\vect{x^*,y^*}$
instead of
$\begin{bsmallmatrix} x^* & y^* \end{bsmallmatrix}^*$

\end{document}
```

And you can input `\vect{x,y,z,t,u,v}`, or `\vect*{\int,\sum,\prod}` or `\vect[\Big]{a,b,\frac{n}{z}}`, etc. like any other delimiter from `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. Substitute `\enspace` for any space you want.

[image]

### Addition

In case what you want is to input `\vect{x,y,z}` and get [x^* y^* z^*]^* just change one command

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dbacc_vect:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpb_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ##1^* } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \enspace }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems really like a robust implementation. Is it possible to put a star on each element of a vector for the starred version?

Comment: Instead of `\enspace` you could add any other spacing like `\quad` (which, in my opinion is too much), or even use matrixes like egreg solutions; and maybe even more useful would be to use `\enspace\allowbreak` so, for long vectors it would break across lines (except if you use the starred version `\vect*{a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a}`). In any case, the basic idea is to use a nice syntax, which, apart from clarity, gives you the power to change the behaviour later.

Comment: My question was rather how to get stars on each element automatically. E.g. if I put ^* in here  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ^* \enspace }, this will not respect the last element

Comment: How to get stars? That was definitely not clear. In any case, I will just update.

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion is to simply type

```
\begin{bmatrix} x^* & y^* \end{bmatrix}
```

perhaps with a proper definition like

```
\newcommand{\rvect}[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}
```

and inputting

```
\rvect{x^* & y^*}
```

If you consider the `&` a nuisance, you can use a comma separated list:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\rvect}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { & }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Text
$\rvect{x^*,y^*}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative, with `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` and `matrix` inside.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\rvect}[1]{[}{]}{\,\makervect{#1}\,}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makervect}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \begin{matrix}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { & }
  \end{matrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Text
$\rvect{x^*,y^*}$

\end{document}
```

You can manually increase the size of the delimiters with the usual optional argument to `\rvect`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I should probably have mentioned this, the problem with bmatrix is that the delimiters take too much space. I do not want to blow up the space between text lines with inline formulas.

Comment: @dbacc Do they? I'm not sure they do.

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture. This should show my problem.

Comment: @dbacc No, you don't get that picture, with your code. Are you using `setspace` and increased interline space? This would explain the problem, and, in this case, it should be mentioned in the question, because it's very important information. Anyway, my second solution doesn't show the issue.

Comment: You're right. It's in my document where its getting that large Could not track it down to any package for now and no I'm not setting setspace or something similar. However, even in the snippet from my answer the brackets from bmatrix are larger

Comment: @dbacc Yes, a bit larger (the size is `\big`), but not as much as that they can influence interline space.

Comment: Just checked it. You're right. Anyway, I'd like to stick with the smaller delimiters. (btw, the spacing problems in my main document came from the commath-package)

Comment: How can the size of the delimiters be changed, by specifying a size like in `\rvect[\Big]{x,y}`? Because it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Patrick It works for me (I refer to the last version, of course). Do you get errors?

Comment: @egreg Alright, thanks for checking! Probably some inference with other settings/packages. No, I don't get any errors it just does not change anything in the output.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late for the answer, but I would like to contribute another way for typesetting row vectors using the `physics` package. According to the package's [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf), you can use the `\mqty` (matrix quantity) macro (see page 7&8, it has a lot of examples). For our case, we just need to write

```
\mqty[X_1 & X_2 & \cdots X_n]
```

for a row vector.

[image]

Please notice that after declaring the `\mqty` environment, vector's elements are surrounded by the square brackets (you can also use different types of outer pairs here, like `| |`,  `( )` or `{ }`).